# Customize MSAL login screen in Android

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

I am developing an android application which uses MSAL to login. Is there anyway to customize the default screen so that I can include a background image and all?

I am referring the below url for MSAL

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customization options are limited to Azure AD to brining and some text fields. It allow you to customize the appearance of the sign-in page with your company logo and custom color schemes. Company branding is available only if you upgrade to premium or Basic edition of Azure AD.

Here are the customization [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization).
Learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding).